# Magento 1.9 product custom options Input type mass update

Tags: magento, magento-1.9

I have magento 1.9 installed with more than 600 products. about 300 products has custom options set with input field drop down.

I want to change input type from drop down to check boxes for all 300 products.

I can only see option of uploading via csv with field _custom_options_type.

Can anyone suggest me how I can update input type efficiently.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Checkbox input-type for product attribute are not set as a normal behaviour there is yes/no select for boolean attributes and multiselect for attribute with many values possible.

In case you speak about admin and you want to have a checkbox for an attribute with multiselect, you will have to develop it yourself (but I am sure you can find a module). The same for yes/no.

In case you speak about frontend, you can display multiselect as checkboxes or yes/no as a checkbox to tick with help of CSS and/or JS.

Feel free to precise your question to get more precise answer.